# Sockets and ServerSockets Server/Client GUI Chat Program

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to learn how sockets and ServerSockets work in Java so I tried to do a Chat Server but at the same time using threading to handle each client. I think I need some fresh eyes on my code because I have no idea why it's not working. The program starts but the client does not connect and the is not created.  I'm fairly certain something is wrong in my client class but I'm not certain what needs to be fixed.  Any help at all, even just a link to a helpful resource, would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Server Code

```
     package chatbox.server;

        import static java.lang.System.out;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.io.PrintStream;
        import java.net.ServerSocket;
        import java.net.Socket;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Scanner;


     public class Server {


    public final static int DEFAULT_PORT = 5000;

    private ServerSocket socket;
    private ArrayList<Socket> clients;


    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Server is now online");
        System.out.println("port: " + port);
        this.socket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Listening socket established");
        System.out.println("Waiting for connections...");
        this.clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();


        while (true) {
            try {
                final Socket connection = this.socket.accept();
                this.clients.add(connection);


                Runnable incomingMsg = new Runnable() {
                    private InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    private InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                            inputStream);
                    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                                String msg = scanner.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Handling message: \"" + msg
                                        + "\"");
                                notifyAllConnections(msg);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                };

                Thread thread = new Thread(incomingMsg);


                thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exc) {
                        try {
                            connection.close();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {

                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            clients.remove(connection);
                            System.out.println("Removed connection");
                        }

                    }
                });
                thread.start();
                System.out.println("Added new connection");
            } catch (IOException exc) {

                System.out
                        .println("Error occurred.");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void notifyAllConnections(String msg) {
        for (Socket sock : this.clents) {
            try {
                OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
                PrintStream printer = new PrintStream(out);
                printer.println(msg);
                printer.flush();
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                System.out.println("Message was not fully broadcast");
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Server server = new Server(
                    Server.DEFAULT_PORT);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.out
                    .println("Could not create the server socket.");
            exc.printStackTrace();
            String servername = "localhost";
            try {
                new Client(servername, 5000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                out.println("Error" + ex.getMessage());

            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Client Code

```
     package chatbox.client

        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import java.io.*;
        import java.util.*;
        import java.net.*;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import static java.lang.System.out;

        public class Client extends JFrame {

    private PrintWriter pw;
    private Scanner scanner;
    private JPanel chatAndSend;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;
    private JScrollPane mainScroll;
    private JTextArea chatText;
    private JScrollPane miniScroll;
    private JButton send;
    private Socket client;

    public Client(String servername, int port) throws Exception {

        this.client = new Socket(servername, port);
        this.scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(
                this.client.getInputStream()));
        this.pw = new PrintWriter(this.client.getOutputStream());

        makeGUI();
        new MessagesThread().start();

    }

    public void makeGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.chatWindow = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        this.chatWindow.setEditable(false);
        this.chatWindow.setLineWrap(true);
        this.mainScroll = new JScrollPane(chatWindow,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        this.add(this.mainScroll, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.chatAndSend = new JPanel();
        this.chatAndSend.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.chatText = new JTextArea(1, 1);
        this.chatText.setLineWrap(true);
        this.miniScroll = new JScrollPane(chatText,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        this.chatAndSend.add(this.miniScroll);
        this.send = new JButton();
        this.send.setText("SEND");
        this.send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                pw.println(chatText.getText());
                pw.flush();
            }
        });
        this.chatAndSend.add(this.send);
        this.add(this.chatAndSend, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
    }

    class MessagesThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            String line;
            try {
                while (true) {
                    line = scanner.nextLine();
                    chatWindow.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

- In the Client MessagesThread class, in the while loop, it should be `while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {`
- In the same class you are appending to a JTextArea from a background thread, something that you should not do.
- In the Client MessagesThread class, implement Runnable rather than extend Thread (general recommendation)
- Even better -- use a SwingWorker, so you can use publish/process to update the JTextArea on the Swing event thread.
- For my money, I'd get the program up and running in a non-GUI version first before trying to put it into a GUI.
- Your spelling errors suggest that the code shouldn't even compile, what with clientss, and clents,... ??? Is this your *real* code? If we can't copy/paste your code and test it, we will have a tough time helping you.

---

**Edit**
I've looked at and run your new code. Do you see that you're trying to create a new Client in a catch block, one that is never called?

Most importantly -- use a debugger when running your code to see what your code is doing or is not doing. Add println statements as well (more of them). If you did this, you'd see that Client's constructor is never called, and would know to look at the code where you try to call it to see why.

Comment: First of all, sorry for the typo.  I must have been typing too fast.  Secondly, I tried your suggestions.  Now, `class MessagesThread implements Runnable` causing me to change `new MessagesThread.start() to MessagesThread.run()`  However the client still doesn't connect to the server.

Comment: So, you're saying that once I move the brace, and call the client in the main method instead of in the try/catch that everything should work?

Comment: @Ashton: No, I'm saying that I see one glaring careless mistake that probably never should never have gotten past your proof-reading. You've still got more work to do including threading work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is one of your problems, but i don't know if its safe to make a foreach loop in the Server class, cause you can iterate from one thread and add things to list from another in the same time, something that can be a problem to foreach loop. Please correct me if i'm wrong. (Or just deleting from foreach could harm it?)